# Caret doesn't run in parallel

Tags: r-caret, domc

Actual parallelizing caret depends on R , caret and doMC packages . As described at  [Parallelizing Caret code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308532/parallelizing-caret-code)

Does anyone working with similar enviroment as I do ? What the max R version where R caret paralellization working correctly ?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=C                  LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] caret_6.0-52    ggplot2_1.0.1   lattice_0.20-31 doMC_1.3.3      iterators_1.0.7 foreach_1.4.2   RStudioAMI_0.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1         magrittr_1.5        splines_3.2.1       MASS_7.3-41         munsell_0.4.2       colorspace_1.2-6   
 [7] minqa_1.2.4         car_2.1-0           stringr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.3          tools_3.2.1         pbkrtest_0.4-2     
[13] nnet_7.3-9          grid_3.2.1          gtable_0.1.2        nlme_3.1-120        mgcv_1.8-6          quantreg_5.19      
[19] MatrixModels_0.4-1  gtools_3.5.0        lme4_1.1-9          digest_0.6.8        Matrix_1.2-0        nloptr_1.0.4       
[25] reshape2_1.4.1      codetools_0.2-11    stringi_0.5-5       BradleyTerry2_1.0-6 scales_0.3.0        stats4_3.2.1       
[31] SparseM_1.7         brglm_0.5-9         proto_0.3-10
```

Update 1 : 
    My code follows :

```
library(doMC) ; registerDoMC(cores=4)
library(caret)
classification_formula <- as.formula(paste("target" ,"~",
                                             paste(names(m_input_data)[!names(m_input_data)=='target'],collapse="+")))

CVfolds <- 2
CVreps  <- 5
ma_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                             number = CVfolds,
                             repeats = CVreps ,
                             returnResamp = "final" ,
                             classProbs = T,
                             summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                             allowParallel = TRUE,verboseIter = TRUE)
 rf_tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = seq(2,32, length.out = 6))
 rf <- train(classification_formula , data = m_input_data , method = "rf", metric="ROC" ,trControl = ma_control, tuneGrid = rf_tuneGrid , ntree = 101)
```

Update 2 : 
   When I run from command line the only one core is working 
   When I run these script from Rstudio the paralell is working since I see 4
   processes via top . But a second after this the error happens :

```
  Error in names(resamples) <- gsub("^\\.", "", names(resamples)) : 
   attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Update 4 :

Hi , it seems the problem was in R session that was terminated . Each time I am start AWS instance I was run the R code with now refresh the R engine . Now each time I refresh Rstudio browser I do Session -> Restart R . Seems it runs .
I am checking now if the same for run the script from Ubuntu command line.

Generally it is running without to finish . Caret parallel on the data level . It means it is able to process each resample on different process . But if sample still big ( 100,000 / 2 ( number of folds = 2) X 2,000 features ) this can be hard to finish for each processor unit . Am I right ?

I think the parallelism must on algorithm level . It means each algorithm run likely to run on several cores . If such algorithm imlpementation avialable in caret ???

Comment: Regarding your `Update 4`, let's say you have a big dataset (100,000 with 2 folds and 2000 features) and you're tuning a `gbm` model. Since `gbm` in `caret` does not support parallelism you will be using only 2 cores of your AWS instance, and it will take a long time to finish.  On the hand, if you were using caret's GA feature selection `gafs` you can parallelize the population, generations, and/or sampling, but in this case you will be limited by the number of cores you have.

Comment: When you have a big, high-dimensional dataset, it might be beneficial to start with a representative subsample (e.g using stratified sampling), use feature selection (e.g PCA, Relief Algorithm, ROC AUC, etc) to reduce the number of predictors, and try tuning different models (e.g. gbm, Random Forest, SVM, etc) on the subsample and select the best performing model. Then, go back and train the best model on the complete dataset.

Comment: When you compare different models, remember, in order to compare apples-to-apples, you must use the same sampling (e.g same CV folds), and same seeds for all models. This can be done in `caret` by using the `index` and `seeds` options in `trainControl()` and other `caret` functions.

Comment: Are you sure gbm not parallelized by caret ? See [link] http://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel.html .  Trying feature selection is my next step . I need to check how well the caret parallelize it . I would share my observations. Sure the subsample must be stratified. You last remark very important in aspect of reproducebility also . I have some example to ensure permanent seeds. Would be tested.

Comment: Thanks , a lot for your answers.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your question `Are you sure gbm not parallelized by caret ? ` To the best of my knowledge, the current implementation of gbm package does not support parallelism ,GBM is, by design, a sequential algorithm (at each new iteration, you fit a new model to try minimize the error of the models fited on previous iterations). On the other hand, caret parallelizes the execution of several models (but not the same model) during the parameters tuning.

Comment: If you're looking for a **distributed** implementation of  `gbm`, have a look at `xgboost`  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/index.html . I've not got the chance to try it yet. So, I can not give more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest release for Linux platforms, R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14, Fire Safety), and paralellization works fine. Can you provide your code that does not work in parallel.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kernlab_0.9-22  doMC_1.3.3      iterators_1.0.7 foreach_1.4.2   caret_6.0-52    ggplot2_1.0.1   lattice_0.20-33

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0         compiler_3.2.2      nloptr_1.0.4        plyr_1.8.3          tools_3.2.2         digest_0.6.8       
 [7] lme4_1.1-9          nlme_3.1-122        gtable_0.1.2        mgcv_1.8-7          Matrix_1.2-2        brglm_0.5-9        
[13] SparseM_1.7         proto_0.3-10        BradleyTerry2_1.0-6 stringr_1.0.0       gtools_3.5.0        MatrixModels_0.4-1 
[19] stats4_3.2.2        grid_3.2.2          nnet_7.3-10         minqa_1.2.4         reshape2_1.4.1      car_2.0-26         
[25] magrittr_1.5        scales_0.3.0        codetools_0.2-11    MASS_7.3-43         splines_3.2.2       pbkrtest_0.4-2     
[31] colorspace_1.2-6    quantreg_5.18       stringi_0.5-5       munsell_0.4.2
```

I've used your code for the `BreastCancer` dataset on my local machine and it worked in parallel without any problem. I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1103.

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)

library(doMC)  
registerDoMC(cores=2)

classification_formula <- as.formula(paste("Class" ,"~",
                                         paste(names(BreastCancer)[!names(BreastCancer)=='Class'],collapse="+")))

CVfolds <- 2
CVreps  <- 5
ma_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = CVfolds,
                           repeats = CVreps ,
                           returnResamp = "final" ,
                           classProbs = T,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           allowParallel = TRUE,verboseIter = TRUE)

rf_tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = seq(2,32, length.out = 6))

#Notice, it might be easier just to use Class~. 
#instead of classification_formula
rf <- train(classification_formula , 
            data = BreastCancer , 
            method = "rf", 
            metric="ROC" ,
            trControl = ma_control, 
            tuneGrid = rf_tuneGrid , 
            ntree = 101)

> rf
Random Forest 

699 samples
 10 predictors
  2 classes: 'benign', 'malignant' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (2 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 341, 342, 342, 341, 342, 341, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

 mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec       ROC SD       Sens SD      Spec SD    
   2    0.9867820  1.0000000  0.0000000  0.005007691  0.000000000  0.000000000
   8    0.9899107  0.9549550  0.9640196  0.002243649  0.006714919  0.017247716
  14    0.9907072  0.9558559  0.9631933  0.003028258  0.012345228  0.008019979
  20    0.9909514  0.9635135  0.9556513  0.003268291  0.006864342  0.010471005
  26    0.9911480  0.9630631  0.9539706  0.003384987  0.005113930  0.010628533
  32    0.9911485  0.9657658  0.9522969  0.002973508  0.004842197  0.004090206

ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 32. 
>
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/62
They discuss the same issue. The problem might be with RStudio. Personally, sometimes I get the same error on Amazon EC2 (using RStudio Server), but when I start a new R session it works.

Comment: See if you can repreduce the error using this dataset
`library(mlbench)`
`data(BreastCancer)`
I will try your code on my local Machine using this data and see if I can produce the same error.

Comment: I've used your code for the `BreastCancer` and it worked in parallel without any errors.  I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1103. See above.

Comment: Hi , I met some your post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494744/caret-setting-the-seeds-inside-the-gafscontrol) . If the way the code works ensure each time the same feature subset is selected ? The question is due GA randomness